# How to convert pptx file (content of xml or json) to fabric js canvas objects?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, powerpoint, fabricjs

I am trying to make an online editing tools like [Canva](https://www.canva.com/). I would like to render the same contents of a power point slide on fabric js canvas for editing (like it does on [Canva](https://www.canva.com/), uploading power point file and make it editable on canvas). After researching online it is not an easy operation and needs some processing. The power point xml/json structure format and canvas json objects rendering formats are very different.

I can extract  the pptx json or xml using `node PPTX2Json` package, there are about 12k lines of json in a single demo slide of pptx file. And simple json structure for rendering on fabric js canvas look like this.

```
{
        "version": "5.3.0",
        "objects": [
            {
                "type": "circle",
                "version": "5.3.0",
                "originX": "center",
                ...
                "startAngle": 0,
                "endAngle": 360
            },
            {
                "type": "triangle",
                "version": "5.3.0",
                "originX": "center",
                "originY": "center",
                "left": 312.5,
                ...
            },
            {
                "type": "rect",
                "version": "5.3.0",
                "originX": "center",
                "originY": "center",
                ...
                "skewX": 0,
                "skewY": 0,
                "rx": 0,
                "ry": 0
            },
            {
                "type": "textbox",
                "version": "5.3.0",
                "originX": "center",
                "originY": "center",
                "left": 563.5,
            }...]
}
```

I would like to convert in the above JSON format from the orginal pptx json formats for editing on canvas, I need the suggestions and the steps of procedure to perform it ???

And also is it possible to convert pptx contents to HTML CSS and then to convert it to fabric canvas, if yes please i need suggestions???

I've been working trying on this for the past three days, but I haven't made any significant progress. Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If i would load a custom `JSON` into fabric I would do something like this :

1. init fabric js
2. loop throught all my JSON objects
3. handle objects creation by type

here is a starter of this reflexion :

```
const FabricCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('yourCanvasElementId') // init you fabric canvas

loadCustomJson = () => {
    const canvas = FabricCanvas
    if (!canvas) return
    const template = JSON.parse(MyJsonFile)
    for(const obj of template.objects){
        createObj(Obj as FabricObject)
    }
    canvas.renderAll()
}

const createObj = (Obj: FabricObject) => {
   const canvas = FabricCanvas
   if (!canvas || !Obj) return

   if(Obj.type === 'textbox') {
      const textboxOptions = Obj

   const textboxContent = textboxOptions.text

   const textboxObj = new fabric.Textbox(
       textboxContent,
       textboxOptions

   )
   canvas.add(textboxObj)
   canvas.renderAll()
   }
   else if(Obj.type === 'rect'){
    ... new fabric.Rect()
   } else if(Obj.type === 'circle'){
   ... new fabric.Circle()

}
```

Now, your canvas should contain objects from the custom JSON